# Return new column z based on min of column x, if column y = value in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I've found similar issues, focusing on returning X based on min of column Y, but I'm having trouble with this function. I'm trying to return the min of column X, if column Y is equal to a particular value.

Here is sample data frame (df):

```
event.id    event.date.timestamp    touchpoint.date.timestamp   touchpoint.type
1   7/16/2015 11:08 11/27/2014 10:34    impression
1   7/16/2015 13:00 6/10/2015 13:19 visit
1   7/16/2015 11:08 12/15/2014 13:24    impression
2   7/16/2015 0:00  4/27/2015 23:04 impression
2   7/16/2015 11:08 11/11/2014 8:01 impression
2   7/16/2015 11:08 11/27/2014 11:50    visit
3   7/16/2015 11:08 12/4/2014 14:36 impression
3   7/16/2015 11:08 11/11/2014 8:01 impression
3   7/16/2015 11:08 12/15/2014 13:21    visit
4   7/16/2015 11:08 11/27/2014 10:01    impression
4   7/16/2015 11:08 11/27/2014 10:22    impression
```

I am using dplyr to group the above table by event.id. I then am trying to summarise, but want to have a new column (first_impression) that only reports the min of the touchpoint.date.timestamp column IF the touchpoint.type column is = "impression".

So far I have

```
> df.new.grouped <- group.by(df, event.id)
> df.new.summarised <- summarise(df.new.grouped
  ,first_imp = min(filter(by.imp_to_click, touchpoint.type == "impression"),touchpoint.date.timestamp))
```

But that's not working for sure. I know you can't filter within, it was just my most recent attempt. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have date classed columns there.

Comment: I suspect the previous comment is right. Can you `dput()` something like the first 10 rows of `df` so we can see and suggest a fix?

Comment: Maybe rank on dates for each I'd, then keep row with minimum date and then filter on touch.point.type?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
df.summarized <- df %>%
    group_by(event.id) %>%
    filter(touchpoint.type=="impression") %>%
    mutate(touchpoint.date.timestamp = as.POSIXct(touchpoint.date.timestamp, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")) %>%
    summarise(first_imp = min(touchpoint.date.timestamp))
```

Following Richard's comment, my assumption is that your date columns are formatted as strings, not dates, so `min()` won't work on them. Your problem is also a great example of how piping with `%>%` can make it easier to spell out and follow what you're doing without creating lots of new objects.

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed that if your minimum date corresponds to a "visit" you don't want anything returned for that id, right?

If that's correct check my example (3 different ways to choose), if that's not correct you can modify it a little bit, or use the answer provided by @ulfelder, which looks perfect.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

# example dataset
dt = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                date = c("2015-01-02","2015-01-04","2015-01-03",
                         "2015-01-11","2015-01-08","2015-01-06"),
                type = c("impression","visit","visit","impression","visit","visit"))

# save as datetime
dt$date = ymd(dt$date) # you'll probably need the ymd_hms function if you have time as well

dt %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(date) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  filter(type=="impression")

dt %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
 filter(min_rank(date)==1 & type=="impression")

dt %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  top_n(1,desc(date)) %>%
  filter(type=="impression")
```

Comment: My dates are formatted as POSIXct dates. My translation to the post is where my fail is (sorry, first post here; I'll learn)

Comment: Also, thank you very much. ulfelder's post did the trick; I just removed the mutate since my date was formatted